# getView in fragment returns sometimes null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app with a ViewPager which contains two fragments: a main fragment and a list fragment. If something in the list is selected, an event is raised which is handled in the activity. The activity switches to the main fragment and calls the "setSelectedItem" method. In this method,
I use getView() to find a specific view to change the text according to the selected item.

Most of the time it works, but sometimes getView returns null and I don't know why.

The pagerAdapter is created in OnCreate of the activity:

```
this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager());
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
```

The pager adapter creates instances of both fragments in its constructor:

```
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.main = MainFragment.newInstance();
    this.list = ListFragment.newInstance();
}
```

This is the method in the activity which is called when an item from the list is selected:

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
((MainFragment)mPagerAdapter.getItem(0)).setSelectedItem(id);
```

And finally this is the line in the setSelectedItem method in the MainFragment which causes the problem:

```
TextView s = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.CurrentSelection);
```

I tried several things I read about but the problem still occurs irregularly.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same problem, and no resolution. My code is littered with if (getView() == null) return; in various places.  If you've solved the problem by now, I'd be interested.

Comment: Can you share the code where you add the fragment to the fragmentmanager? It's possible getView will return null if onCreateView (part of the fragment life cycle) has not been called for the fragment - ie the fragment has not completely been added to the activity.

Comment: Where are you calling "TextView s"? Is this in public View getView in the Fragment?

Comment: Share more code, and this will have a solution for sure. In my experience when you have a ViewPager and lets say you have 3 pages, while you are in page 1 the page 3 is not created. It is not created until you scroll to page 1. and when go to page 3 the page 1 is destroyed. So be careful on how to work with them. I use ViewPager with fragments and use GUI interaction in onViewCreated (or similar) for each fragment.

Comment: I handled this by manually keeping my own reference to the main view and not depending on getView()

Answer (score 0):

To start, I am not 100% sure, but I have a couple of points I need to mention. First, I don't like how you are using `this` and `super` like that, they seem to be vague, I believe a better way is to be more accurate considering pre-compile you are aware of their values. I think if you change your code to as following, it would help (just a hunch).

```
// No need for 'this' and 'super' here, you are within the activity
mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

---

```
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // No need for 'this' here, you are within the class
    main = MainFragment.newInstance();
    list = ListFragment.newInstance();
}
```

---

```
// No need for 'super' here, you are within the activity
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
((MainFragment)mPagerAdapter.getItem(0)).setSelectedItem(id);
```

---

```
// Here use 'getActivity()' instead of 'getView()'
TextView s = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.CurrentSelection);
```

Let me know what happens, cheers.

Comment: The topic is quite old and still no accepted answer.Have same issue and looking for a solution.One important notice:the issue is repro when android kills hosting activity(on out of mem for instance).Android tries to restart activity in this case.For some reason onCreateView doesn't get called after fragment recreation instead its called before(!).To surely reproduce the issue one could set `destroy every activity as soon as  user leaves it` in the `developer options`.Then just pause the app by pressing home button and restore it.